# where to store confirm data that a child window captures?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

What's best practice for a WPF windows application re where to store confirm data that a child window captures?

That is, say from main page you click "configure" to jump to a configuration window/dialog.  Where should the config data be stored so that when finished the main screen can access it when the user clicks on a button that initiates an event that needs the config data.

Would putting the data as instance variables in the main window class be the normal way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect that you are persisting the configuration data in some way (file, db, etc.)

I would write the configuration window to be interact with the objects that model that data and be independent of the main window.

Also since you probably only need a single instance of configuration data it makes sense to make it a singleton. You could then create an event that is fired when your configuration data changes that your main screen handles.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to or can't use database, and want to persist configuration changes then use Application Settings.

Comment: so use the Application Settings like global variables for the application correct?